# Static Wallet Address

Tags: wallet, address, address-reuse

How do I make my account static so the address stays the same. The bitcoin wallet address keeps changing and I need to figure out how to make it stay the same

Comment: Hi Kristina, which wallet software are you using?--Also, generally address reuse has downsides for the financial privacy of you and your business partners, and very few upsides. Perhaps it would help if you described why you want to keep a fixed address rather than using a new address for every payment as is recommended.

Comment: I'm trying to get something deposited into my bank account and they have the wallet address but they want me to verify that it's a static so the address didn't change.

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't ever a reason to have a static bitcoin address, as @Murch mentioned in the comments, doing so has very real downsides, and no real upside.

That said, your wallet will (and should) present you with a new address for each and every payment you receive, **however**, any past address your wallet has presented to you will continue to work to receive funds in the future.

In other words, if you open your wallet and copy down the address, but then open/close your wallet 100 times (and get presented with 100 different addresses in the process), that won't change anything about the validity of that original address. You can still receive funds to it, it is still a part of your wallet. Any good wallet will eventually contain a large collection of addresses!

> I'm trying to get something deposited into my bank account and they have the wallet address but they want me to verify that it's a static...

I'm curious who the 'they' is in this. Its hard to say without more information, but odd requests like this are sometimes the hallmarks of a scammer.

Answer (score 1):

A wallet can have many addreses not just one.

Each of those addresses lasts forever and never changes. You can receive as many transactions as you want to any address that you pick.

Re-using one address means a loss of privacy (other people can see transactions to that address) - this is why your wallet creates a new address every time you click the address button.

Elsewhere in your wallet's menus you will find a list of all generated addresses. It might just show the ones that have already received money but some wallets will allow you to see *all* the addresses, including ones that have not yet been used in any transaction.

---

Your question and comments use words like "account", "deposited", "bank account" but remember Bitcoin is cash, not an account.

Answer (score -2):

Not having a fixed address is idiotic, has absolutely no upsides except to people who want to be deceptive.  There is no relevance whatsoever to a floating not static address other than to make crypto completely useless for legitimate stable use.

It seems trolls hit every comment section telling people that they want that address to change.  Having it change makes bitcoin a freaking toy.

Generate a paper wallet and stick with it if saboteurs in the coding community continue to flood the ether with "meta" address wallets that have absolutely no repeatability and no usefulness except for criminal use.  There, you got real advice.